# How to extract a single tweet from the search results and store it in a variable named t?

Tags: python, twitter

I am following http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001583/ch01.html
to learn how to get information from tweets using Python (jupyter).

Under "Analyzing the 140 Characters", the author say's the following:

> let's assume that we've extracted a single tweet from the search results and stored it in a variable named t.

He then continues, using this variable t to get more information out of that one tweet. But how do I extract a single tweet from the search results and store it in a variable named t?

I would like to do so to follow his code, i.e. using "t['text']" and what follows.

I can get the text using the following code:

```
search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=count)
one_tweet = [status['text']
                for status in search_results['statuses'][0:1]]
print(one_tweet)`
```

What I, however, would like to have is more like

```
one_tweet = [status
                for status in search_results['statuses'][0:1]]
print(one_tweet['text'])
print(one_tweet['screen_name'])`
```

In other words, save the whole tweet and then specify what I would like to print

After

```
search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=count)
print search_results
```

I get the following:

```
{{u'search_metadata': {u'count': 100, u'completed_in': 0.148, u'max_id_str': u'714086757604659200', u'since_id_str': u'0', u'refresh_url': u'?since_id=714086757604659200&q=%23dopa&include_entities=1', u'since_id': 0, u'query': u'%23dopa', u'max_id': 714086757604659200}, u'statuses': [{u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': .....}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have retrieved the tweet as in the snippet before in that source

```
search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=count)
```

the results are returned as a list and you can simply iterate over the `search_result`s:

```
for t in search_results["statuses"]:
   print t['text']
```

Comment: I get the following error:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

and it shows me that the problem is in the last line, when I want to print the text.

Comment: If I just use `print t` the result is

`search_metadata` and
`statuses`

Comment: do `search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=count); print search_results` first to see what's in there.

Comment: I get "all" the information about the hashtag I used for q: too much to copy in here. A text of the metadata I would guess

Comment: First few hundred characters will be sufficient. Pls add it as an update to the question.